# getting diffrent results of dpi of image with diffrent methods

Tags: php, image, centos7, dpi

I want to allow only those images whose dpi is 72, for that i have compared two results.

1. Linux command identify from imagemagick
2. php function

e.g

```
<?php
$imagedpi = get_dpi($imagename);
if($imagedpi[0] ==72 && $imagedpi[1]==72){
//success
}else{
//fail
}
?>
```

when i am trying linux command i am getting below outout

```
<?php
function get_dpi($imagename){
    system('identify -units PixelsPerInch -format "%x %y" '.$imagename);

    //after processing it is giving us output as array(x,y)
    return array(x,y)
}
?>
```

Its output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 72
    [1] => 72
)
```

PHP code written as

```
<?php
function get_dpi($imagename){        
    $image = imagecreatefrompng($imagename);
    $imageresolution = imageresolution($image);
    return $imageresolution;
}
?>
```

Its output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 96
    [1] => 96
)
```

I want to go with linux command(identify) as on production server we are having PHP 5.6 in which imagecreatefrompng function not working, but i got little confusion why identify command giving me output as 72,72 where as php code giving me output as 96 for the same image.

I am using centos7 Operating system with PHP 7.4.19  installed.

I  am not sure about the behavior of identify command if it is giving me cached output or what?

Its not like they are behaving different for every image but for images i have converted in to specific dpi i am getting same results with both methods but if i picked any random image then sometime i am getting such behavior.

Sample image i am trying
[image]

any help appreciated.

Comment: Post the image that shows that issue. Is it a PDF, EPS, etc?

Comment: seems, 72 dpi is the default value for new images, regardless of how it was in the original

Comment: @fmw42  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Usf7s.png  image which i am trying added in description too.

Comment: @splash58 so do we have any workaround on this?

Comment: Your file has no density defined for it. So each system assigns its own default value. Some default to 72 and some to 96.

Comment: thanks mate. so thats why my system returning as 72 for such images.since i needed this for safari web integration i have tried with 100 dpi and is working fine so guess same function will work fine for 100 dpi as default value is 72